# How do I find a date in php using timestamps?

Tags: php

I have a timestamp, say $now, I need to find the timestamp for, say, 45 days after the date of $now. What do I do?

Answer (score 1):

you can use [`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

```
$the_45_days_later = strtotime('+45 day', $now);
```

the precision of the timestamp is not rounded to `00:00:00`,
but followed exactly the time that `$now` belong to

the other answers has show using pure seconds calculation,
which is precise too

```
$the_45_days_later = $now+(86400*45);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
                                 //sec min  hour  day
$fourty_five_days_after = time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 45;
```

Answer (score 0):

1 day has 86400 seconds so the code is:

```
$now = time();
$after = $now + 45*86400;
```

Answer (score 0):

This should give what you need:

```
$new_ts = $now+45*24*60*60;
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using the (PHP 5 >= 5.2.0) [DateTime](http://nl.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) functions:

```
$iTimeStamp = time();
$oDateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat("U", $iTimeStamp);
$oDateTime->add(new DateInterval('P45D'));
echo $oDateTime->getTimeStamp();
```

Answer (score 0):

from http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php :

```
$a = new DateTime("now");
var_dump($a);
date_add($a, date_interval_create_from_date_string("45 days"));
var_dump($a);

object(DateTime)#1 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(19) "2011-08-24 09:00:03"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(16) "America/New_York"
}
object(DateTime)#1 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(19) "2011-10-08 09:00:03"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(16) "America/New_York"
}
```